# Undefined control sequence \DeclareMicrotypeSet

Tags: microtype

I am trying to compile the tex file for CV template of 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grayclhn/safecv/master/template-grad.tex.

The error message is :
! Undefined control sequence.
l.45 \DeclareMicrotypeSet
                         {all}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

Any help is appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the problematic code as MWE.

Comment: [*"If you find problems, please report an issue at https://github.com/grayclhn/safecv."*](https://github.com/grayclhn/safecv)

Comment: no problem here if I do `pdflatex template-grad`, so you have to tell us a bit more...